# Find the sum of numbers present in a string separated by spaces in between using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am finding it difficult in writing python code for the below scenario

I have a list called

```
sume=['12 1929 8827','8837 139']
```

I converted the string to int but it is showing error because of the " " in between.

How to calculate the sum of the digits by eliminating the " " in between.

Answer should be 19744.

Comment: How do you get 19746? `12+1929+8827+8837+139` gives 19744.

Comment: You have two strings in `sume` - you need to split each string; make an int of each item in the split string; add each int to a *variable* holding the total.

Comment: `import numpy as np;np.array(' '.join(sume).split(),'int').sum()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```py
parsed = []
array = ['12 1929 8827','8837 139']
for string in array:
    for component in string.split(' '):
        parsed.append(int(component))

sum = reduce(lambda a, x: a + x, parsed)
```

Or more simply (as pointed out by @wwii):

```py
parsed = []
array = ['12 1929 8827','8837 139']
for string in array:
    for component in string.split(' '):
        parsed.append(int(component))

sum = sum(parsed)
```

Or even more simply (also as pointed out by @wwii):

```py
accumulated = 0
array = ['12 1929 8827','8837 139']
for string in array:
    for component in string.split(' '):
        accumulated += int(component)

sum = sum(parsed)
```

Comment: Or just `total = sum(parsed)` - please don't shadow Python builtins and keywords ... by using them as variable names. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum

Comment: Also, if the list of ints isn't needed for anything else, `parsed` could be `parsed = 0` and and instead of `parsed.append...` in the loop, it could be `parsed += int(component)` - then the final summation isn't needed

Answer (score 1):

You need to split by space and sum those numbers, one approach is the following:

```
sum(number for word in ['12 1929 8827','8837 139'] for number in map(int, word.split()))
```

**Output**

```
19744
```

A more robust approach is to provide a default value in case the cast fails:

```
def to_int(text, default=0):
    try:
        return int(text)
    except ValueError:
        return default

text_numbers = ['12 1929 8827','8837 139']

print(sum(number for word in text_numbers for number in map(to_int, word.split())))
```

**Output**

```
19744
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `str.split()` method to split by space:

```
total = sum(sum(int(n) for n in i.split())
            for i in sume)
#                    ^^ that's your starting list
```

This takes each string on numbers in the list and splits it by space, returning the sum of it. Then each of these 'sums' are fed into the outer `sum` call to get their total. This would look like the following when expanded:

```
total = 0
for i in sume:
    i = i.split()
    for n in i:
        total += int(n)
```

Remember that `split()` returns a list of *strings*, so you still need to cast each item to `int` before summing it.

Comment: Don't name your variable `sum`... for reasons that should be obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Use `sum`+`map` and `str.split()`

```
>>> sume=['12 1929 8827','8837 139']
>>> elems = [sum(map(int, s.split())) for s in sume]
[10768, 8976]
```

If you need the sum of *all elements*, can use `sum` again

```
>>> sum(elems)
19744
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution is `sum(map(int, ' '.join(sume).split()))`